How to Implement Azure AD Client Credentials Flow for Application Permissions in a NestJS Application?
I am working on integrating Azure AD authentication in a NestJS application. I need to acquire both delegated and application permissions to access resources in Microsoft Graph. Specifically, I need permissions for User.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, and Group.ReadWrite.All. While the delegated permissions are working fine with the Authorization Code Flow, I am struggling to get the application permissions using the Client Credentials Flow. How can I properly configure and implement the Client Credentials Flow in my NestJS application to acquire the necessary application permissions?

 import { BadRequestException, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  ConfidentialClientApplication,
  CryptoProvider,
  ResponseMode,
} from '@azure/msal-node';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { ERRORS } from '../shared/errors';
import { GRAPH_API_URL } from '../shared/constants';
import { UserApi } from '../types/api';

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftAuthService {
  private msalInstance: ConfidentialClientApplication;
  private cryptoProvider: CryptoProvider;

  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {
    this.msalInstance = new ConfidentialClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
        authority: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_AUTHORITY'),
        clientSecret: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      },
    });

    this.cryptoProvider = new CryptoProvider();
  }

  // Get Auth Code URL for Delegated Permissions
  async getAuthCodeUrl(state: string, requestId: string) {
    try {
      const { challenge, verifier } = await this.cryptoProvider.generatePkceCodes();
      const authCodeUrlRequest = {
        state,
        scopes: [
          'User.ReadWrite.All',
          'Application.ReadWrite.All',
          'Group.ReadWrite.All',
          'openid',
        ],
        redirectUri: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_REDIRECT_URI'),
        responseMode: ResponseMode.FORM_POST,
        codeChallenge: challenge,
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
      };

      const authCodeUrl = await this.msalInstance.getAuthCodeUrl({
        ...authCodeUrlRequest,
        prompt: 'consent',
        extraQueryParameters: {
          requestId: requestId,
        },
      });
      return {
        authCodeUrl,
        pkceCodes: { challenge, verifier },
        requestId,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error:', error);
      throw new BadRequestException(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  // Acquire Token By Authorization Code for Delegated Permissions
  async acquireTokenByCode(code: string, state: string, session: any) {
    try {
      const tokenResponse = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenByCode({
        redirectUri: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_REDIRECT_URI'),
        scopes: [
          'User.ReadWrite.All',
          'Application.ReadWrite.All',
          'Group.ReadWrite.All',
          'openid',
        ],
        code,
        codeVerifier: session.pkceCodes.verifier,
        state: state,
      });
      return tokenResponse.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error acquiring token by code:', error);
      throw new BadRequestException(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  // Acquire Token Using Client Credentials for Application Permissions
  async getApplicationAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const tokenResponse = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
        scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
      });
      return tokenResponse.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error acquiring application token:', error);
      throw new BadRequestException(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  async getUserInfo(accessToken: string): Promise<UserApi> {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${GRAPH_API_URL}/me`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      const userInfo = (await response.json()) as UserApi;
      if (userInfo?.error) {
        throw new Error(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
      return userInfo;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error fetching user info:', error);
      throw new BadRequestException(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  async getOrganizationInfo(accessToken: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${GRAPH_API_URL}/organization`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error fetching organization info:', error);
      throw new BadRequestException(ERRORS.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
}



Initially, I registered one application and granted permissions of Application type as below:


Note that, you cannot call "/me"  endpoint with token generated with
client credentials flow. Alternatively, use /users/userId
instead of "/me" to get user information in app-only scenarios.

To acquire token using client credentials flow and get the user information in Nest JS app, I used below sample code files:
microsoft-auth.service.ts:
// src/microsoft-auth/microsoft-auth.service.ts
import { ConfidentialClientApplication, Configuration } from '@azure/msal-node';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftAuthService {
  private confidentialClient: ConfidentialClientApplication;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MicrosoftAuthService.name);

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    const config: Configuration = {
      auth: {
        clientId: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
        authority: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_AUTHORITY'),
        clientSecret: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      },
    };

    this.confidentialClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
  }

  async acquireToken(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const result =
        await this.confidentialClient.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
          scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
        });
      return result.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Failed to acquire token', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

test.controller.ts:
// src/test/test.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MicrosoftAuthService } from '../microsoft-auth/microsoft-auth.service';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
  constructor(
    private readonly microsoftAuthService: MicrosoftAuthService,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  @Get('token')
  async getToken(): Promise<string> {
    const accessToken = await this.microsoftAuthService.acquireToken();
    return `Access token: ${accessToken}`;
  }

  @Get('user')
  async getUser(): Promise<any> {
    const accessToken = await this.microsoftAuthService.acquireToken();
    const userId = this.configService.get<string>('USER_ID'); 
    try {
      const response = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.get(
          `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          },
        ),
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return `Error fetching user info: ${error.message}`;
    }
  }
}

Output:

When I ran below URLs in browser, I got access token and API response successfully like this:
http://localhost:3000/test/token


http://localhost:3000/test/user


